# ramified in prime degree cyclic extension implies totally ramified in prime power cyclic extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb Q$ be a prime power cyclic extension, say of degree $p^n$.
If a prime $q$ ramifies in the subfield $K_1$ of $K$ such that $[K_1:\mathbb Q]=p$, can one assert that $q$ is totally ramified in $K$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the source of your question, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Look at the inertia group of $q$. If this was smaller than the whole Galois group, it would fix a field that contains $K_1$. But then $q$ would be unramified in $K_1$, contradicting the hypothesis.